# Maximum Sum of elements of array which is not divisible by M, deleting/avoiding at most K consequtive array elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Given: **N**, **K**, **M** and **A**(array)

**N** = No. of elements in the array
**K** = Maximum consequtive array elements that can be avoided/not considered in the answer
**|A|** = N

Starting from the last index of the array, you have to find the maximum sum that can be obtained by using the elements of the array, such that at any instant the sum is not divisibe by **M**. The sum can be aquired by traversing from the last index to the first index of the array (*in order*), and you have a choice to either **include** that element into the final answer, or **avoid** it.

There are two conditions :

1. When an item is **include**d, the total sum of all elements included till that moment (including the current element that is being included), should **not be divisible by M**.
2. When an item is **avoid**ed, it has to be kept in mind that you can **avoid at most K consequtive array elements** at once.

**Note** : It is strictly required to start from the last index, and skipping any index will count towards the limit on the maximum consequtive elements that can be avoided (i.e K).

If there exists no way to traverse from the last index to the first index by satisfying the two conditions at all instances of the traversal, we have to return back **-1**, or else return back the **maximum sum possible**.

**Constraints :**

```
2 <= N <= 10^5 
1 <= K <= 10
1 <= M <= 20
```

**Example 1 :**

```
N = 5
K = 1 
M = 2
A = [1, 2, 3 ,4, 5]

Output : 5 + 4 + 2 = 11
```

**Example 2 :**

```
N = 5
K = 2
M = 2
A = [3, 4, 2, 6, 8]

Output = -1
```

**Example 3 :**

```
N = 7
K = 2 
M = 2
A = [1,4,2,6,3,7,7]

Output : 7 + 6 + 2 + 4  = 19
```

Comment: Could you show own thoughts?

Comment: Observing the low limits of K, I initially wondered if the problem could be solved with a DP table of N x K. But I could not define well what dp[i][j] could mean. Possibly, for each i for N-1 to 0, greedily fill the dp table for each j from 0 to K+1, where j would mean if the last j items were ignored/avoided. We would have to check if we are allowed to skip that many elements from the end, as we can skip at most K consecutively. I came up a recursive approach, which can be proved that it works, but it's definetly an O(2^N) solution. But, I feel this should be a DP problem, I'm not sure though

Comment: Do upvote the question ! It'll help the post reach a wider audience, and possibly we can reach somewhat closer to something that looks like a solution.

Comment: @ParthPrratimChatterjee I'd consider accepting kcsquared's answer rather than mine. Their test suite shows my current code fails for some cases.

Comment: done @גלעדברקן Thanks for your the code though. It worked as a background to reach a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do 3-D dynamic programming to solve this, very similarly to the other post. Here's the definition of the formula I'm using:

```c
Let dp[i][k][r], 0 <= i < N, 0 <= k <= K, 0 <= r < M
be the maximum valid sum achievable after processing indices [i, i+1, ..., N-1]
such that index i is our kth consecutive skip and the sum's remainder is r (mod M).
We want max(dp[0][_][_])

dp[i][k][r] = -INF            if k + i > N
            = -INF            if r == 0 and k + i /= N
            = -INF            if r /= 0 and k + i == N
            = 0               if r == 0 and k + i == N
            = dp[i+1][k-1][r] if k > 0  and r /= 0

            = A[i] + max(dp[i+1][j][(r-A[i]) % M] over all j), if k == 0
```

The formula is quite long, due to the fact that the initial empty sum of `0` (which is technically divisible by `M`) is allowed but all others are not. There's also an initial value of the formula not included above: if `A[N-1]` (the last element) is not divisible by `M`, then `dp[N-1][0][A[N-1]%M]` is `A[N-1]`. You can shorten this formula by two lines, but you do have at least 4 distinct patterns to match.

The time and space complexity are `O(NMK)`, but the space complexity can be reduced to `O(MK)` by only ever storing the last two rows of your DP table.

Here's a Python computation of that DP formula:

```py
def f(A: List[int], N: int, K: int, M: int) -> int:
    assert N == len(A)

    if M == 1:
        return -1

    dp = [[[-math.inf for _ in range(M)] for _ in range(K + 1)] for _ in range(N)]

    for i in range(N):
        k = N - i
        if 0 <= k <= K:
            dp[i][k][0] = 0

    if A[N - 1] % M != 0:
        dp[N - 1][0][A[N - 1] % M] = A[N - 1]

    for i in reversed(range(N - 1)):
        elem = A[i]

        # When k == 0
        for r in range(1, M):
            for j in range(K + 1):
                dp[i][0][r] = max(dp[i][0][r], elem + dp[i + 1][j][(r - elem) % M])

        # When k > 0
        for k in range(1, K + 1):
            for r in range(1, M):
                dp[i][k][r] = dp[i + 1][k - 1][r]

    ans = max([max(x) for x in dp[0]])

    return ans if math.isfinite(ans) else -1
```

[If you'd like to test this code and other answers, plus a slow brute force solution, here's an online code-runner](https://tio.run/##rVffb6M4EH7nr5jrarXQki7p7b5ETaRI@9ZL7@HudA8IIZqY1hswOePsNqryt/dmbAOGkO6tdEgJYM9888Mzn83uoJ4q8evray6rEhQvGfByV0kFOybzdF3thWLSs2Nlpp6aZ5mJTVU2bxylVFUVtWeADjsuHhuopTiE8IWvVQi/8Rr/f98pXomsCOEP9s@eiTUL4c/9rsDbXwJnQlhntfK8DcshT9UT47L2lyHch3AXwiqYeYDXZgdziON4khdVpvwLLvKLIIFLWEFeSdgCF@TlI/Pv4AqmOEXDohu@DxJPI2WiRqgejpkgBe4owASmIUz0z3rRiDnmohBKLrQ0R4@1cUe60ZCdxmowTZdg39N6X6Jjy5gnCOJvdjEnsCTeJrFMgOfo3C1or4AVNYMoGIWRCOI3eO8xgd6JGGE3uHNc6GffGQnBMU3WGvNbWEBkTPeyN2IApUWFhVJzUasMl1w7JENMghqJnq51JRQXezYKtoX5HKJxxdZ1bYICssG/LR0lJ1UwJm@qhVKET@HQWPCToZz6SsijIHS9g3rLd@B/z2rI6po/CraBTL0hj@0DqtpBlevHdbVh8FBU621wVmngU/gGOhfrYr9hZyXOJf6tEhxZB@9nF0ErSKb2UmhZ6pWu9LQOFZ6t3anXkA02LvOXM01UMUpg7d/PSBQb2d5XM6M6WdDdVCAuBRIgtiIWZcGEv7QeoNkVjU27QrVOkc0eixG5XmO0mhtSlxuS4ZDLZ@kInw1py@kvbBtNGNxzeimC2znO4N9dv6H6SxK1MS1jTToJkQn80utDVDFzqBO7colmMvM@dJN9Y7JmG9@hWZcxWcEaHuwq4R38/cSE5QHvDLFOu@3Clfg6zOXsTDVGJ4QYGULULl05vPg1iX2JjtNEoOMNRnxdDFzd9lwd8@XHAZ3S9whbuxsdBRPT33Og4Z8JHnWiZLxxTGXWORe4zVPvnLbNg9wrliLY@n/qnrZ5bt9sHjT@yFT6LSv2zOdiw9es7mNbIDsXT6a0lepE662TStBOYY0vhg3Q2WtGFG5ibsEVeFKhnmoHxL5MEZISTbE0TvWWfazqG73hUQHH0icmGeI1nmIbDHZD7cWkk12YEE8L5TSgJqgr3WAW4MQASbw3XBb9V1SbmgbTG64iYpqxB6YFrTolaF2VDymmbyRP2AH3wyNVo1KRfHsWvaYhLjI6bNYNtwRhCz5ItPWCGoMeQ6eyNHbQcboRJY97RXYHC6yE0QqK3L4idds6ZYYnResIVYCSPCuodqYRXF7CJz2Bm1KaSakTMocbM5Y9O2PTG6@VJIqftjL6bdrNlr1ZertxZi3TRq2AHZhGDfnT9wAmJZVMn@3nrtcfP6Kg57b0UHwBnzvuR62O2DqYoJdTEnp/anYOn/t53kmUGT835RdLBRobXvB2RF7bmG@dF/crx0fiADwgSJXqydn1p/zonj26dJuPn2u6Ge@dFQrdpXG0ywMN0mY/qk2JDtuUB8O9vcFLeoDbc75sDZRzxkPp8py0NVwOvNWbRZ/bTRDxDIm9C/egzR1IvyUUrPAWQJ@pfqTprrk1jgeLBmdsrfOLLzzPZyitN6oXo3UMtZIZatSPUAm4n79Yy0e4m5P49ggr/VAeB2d9Y8H4PDYTP2NR6pS2G6gRHpz/HyTLttjqGFSaiqxkaUq1@yFNqfHT9IMJzKm6OfRr0nYiscTr678)

Comment: Thanks ! I think this solution is clearer. Abstractly, apart from the other cases, the two main cases were, when k == 0 , we are starting a streak with 0 consecutive skips so we consider all the previous entries with 0 to K skips with the required remainder value , added with the current element. And for k > 0, we are already starting with a skip that's greater than 0, which means we have already made k-1 skips before, so look for the max value in previous results for the requried remainder, with k-1 skips. Is this summary somewhat correct ?

Comment: @ParthPrratimChatterjee That's exactly right. The slightly unusual part of the formula, which you explained perfectly, is that I'm calling the action of using the item a 'streak of 0 consecutive skips'.